# Laravel didn't remember login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I use the manual authentication in Larave, here is my function of code

```
public function doLogin(){
  // create our user data for the authentication
  $userdata = array(
    'username' => Input::get('username'),
    'password' => Input::get('password')
  );

  // attempt to do the login
  if (Auth::attempt($userdata,true)) {
    return (Auth::check() ? 'true' : 'false');
  }
  else {
    // validation not successful, send back to form
    return (Auth::check() ? 'true' : 'false');
  }
}
```

After logging in, the `Auth::check` returned true. But after browsing to protected routes, which have this construct function

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

the middleware redirects me to the login page again, even after login.

`Auth` middleware has never been modified. Are there any modifications I needed to do?

I also tried my custom middleware:

```
class LoginCheck
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if (!Auth::check()) {
          if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
              return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
          } else {
              return redirect('login');
          }
      }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Still not working, means Auth::check() is returning `false`.

Cookies are configured to store session, and still not working, too.

Comment: Try `dd(\Auth::user())` in `__construct` function

Comment: Thank you, Akshay. Would you please kindly give me further clarification on how to do this?

Comment: Inside whatever controller you're accessing from these routes, have it look like this
    `public function __construct()
    {
        dd(Auth::user());
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }`

Comment: Thank you, `null` returned.

Comment: Have you change your session config?

Comment: Weigreeen: Thank you. Seems like not yet.

Comment: Weigreen: Now configured to use cookies, still not working.

Comment: Out of the box Laravel uses the **email** for login, have you made any changes to use **username**?

Comment: TheFallen: Thank you, I have written my own form, which the forms' names corresponds the table headers' names.

Comment: Are you using Laravel 5.2? If yes, please use the **web** middleware for the routes.

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, but...

I created a new Laravel project. Copied all the MVC and routes (only that) but excluding everything about `auth`. Then I did `php artisan make:auth`, and it worked, and I have literally no idea why.

Seems like I must have messed with something really, bad.

By the way, thanks for all the help!